# Typeahead doesn't work with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I cannot make it work. I don't have any error on the console. The list doesn't appear at all.

Here is my html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>


<form method="POST" class="search-form" name="search-form">
    <input id="keywords" name = "searchtext" type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Enter your text..." autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit">Search Now</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

      // applied typeahead to the text input box
      $('#keywords').typeahead({
        name: 'keywords',

        // data source
        local: ['pattern recognition', 'supervised learning', 'support vector machines'],

        // max item numbers list in the dropdown
        limit: 10
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of typeahead.js are you using?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri I downloaded the latest from here https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js I think it is the 0.10.2

Comment: I don't think the library works the way you are trying to use it any longer.  Have you looked at the [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)?

Comment: hmmm I tried to use a tutorial I found in web. I will try to implement one of the examples from your link in my project.

Comment: I suspect most tutorials are out of date.  The library was just updated in the past couple of months and is not backwards compatible with previous versions.

Comment: @Dhaulagiri Your edit left this question with nothing but a pair of tags that have almost no visibility, effectively hiding the question. It needs at least one major tag. If you don't think [tag:twitter-bootstrap] is appropriate, then add something else, like [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Bootstrap 3 does not include a typeahead library like 2.3 and earlier did. The typeahead.js library you are including works much differently, and there are some great examples on how to use it [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

Comment: You forgot to include the links! :)

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that